# ActionExecutingContext ActionParameters gets an object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

**I have a controller like this**

```
public ActionResult ChangePassword(LG_CRD_PASSWORD_MODIFY_MAP pLG_CRD_PASSWORD_MODIFY_MAP)
{
    ....
}
```

**And an OnActionExecuting Method**

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var param = filterContext.ActionParameters;
}
```

I'm not being able to extract values from the object parameter

[image]

[image]

Comment: On the contrary, the images show that you *did* get the parameter named `LG_CRD_PASSWORD_MODIFY_MAP`. If it doesn't have the *contents* you expected, perhaps you should post the code that makes the call to the action. BTW, *why* are you using a dictionary instead of individual parameters, or at least a class with properties?

Comment: I got the parameter but not being able to extract individual object property value like "USER_ID","USER_NAME","NEW_PASSWORD" etc

Comment: Post the code that makes the action call. If there was a problem with deserialization or MVC you wouldn't get the parameter at all.

Comment: the action was called by a form post from strongly typed razor view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrieve object from dictionary:

```
LG_CRD_PASSWORD_MODIFY_MAP extractedObj = param.Single(x => x.Key == "pLG_CRD_PASSWORD_MODIFY_MAP").value;
```

For example:

```
var prop = extractedObj.CURRENT_PASSWORD;
```

Comment: Still not being able to extract individual object property :(

Comment: The OP isn't asking how to get access to the parameters, he already has access to them. He asks why some of the parameter *value's* properties are empty

Comment: While this maybe can answer the question, it's better to provide some explanations about how this code help.

Comment: @NsTurjo Could you confirm what Panagiotis is saying; are you not expecting those properties to be null?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos no, the null properties are left empty intentionally. 
But i'm not being able to get those "USER_ID","USER_NAME","NEW_PASSWORD" etc values into other variables.

Comment: Is the extractedObj object being left null or is there a definitive error? - try latest edit...

Comment: 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,object>' does not contain a definition for 'CURRENT_PASSWORD' and no extension method 'CURRENT_PASSWORD' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,object>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
...... Getting this error

Comment: Code adjusted... see above (perhaps requires implicit casting?)